# Google Ads are not displaying on website page in PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I have integrated Google ads in one of my website's page. But the problem is when I loads the page, ads are not displaying.

What I have tried in the code is given below:

```
<body>
    <p>some text about website</p>
    <div>
        <script src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
        <ins class="adsbygoogle" data-ad-client="ca-pub-1234567890123456" data-ad-slot="123456789"></ins>
        <script>(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({}); </script>
    </div>
</body>
```

Please correct me if I have done something wrong.
Thanks!

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: There are no errors in console.

Comment: Have you got an adblock running?

Comment: I am using Firefox browser and not running any external adblock. Browser settings were set to standard. But I changed it to custom and no content is blocked right now.

Answer (score 2):

Please let me answer this question.

Based on my experience, Google Andsense only show its ad on pages with enough content and high traffic.

Try to do following tricks:

1. Add a unique content / article with at least 1000 words on a page of your website;
2. Place 1 link unit of your Google Adsense ad on that page because it's the easiest one to show up;
3. Share it on your social media fanpage with thousands of followers to get high traffic into that page.

That's it. Do again and again then I hope your Google Adsense ad will show up continuesly. Then, you can customize up more ads on your website.

I hope my answer will help up you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the Google Ad Sense troubleshooter:

https://support.google.com/adsense/troubleshooter/7049023#ts=7049024%2C9146143

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. If you don't get any errors, then this is because not having enough traffic(True traffic not paid). Try to get more traffic daily and you will get your ads again.

```
 1. Basic SEO(on-site and off-site)

 2.Social media Marketing.

 3. Good content
```

will get more traffic. That's how I got ads back. Hope this helps.